# how to get the current date and time using embedded C language in keil compiler

Tags: embedded, keil

using Embedded C in keil compiler how to get the current date and time? what header files need to be included for this purpose?

Comment: Which Keil compiler;  8051, 8x251, C166 or ARM (which is in fact ARM RealView)?

Answer (score 1):

In the Keil standard library, the time.h `time_t time( time_t *timeptr )` function is an empty "weak-link" stub or undefined function that you must implement to access whatever time resource is available on your hardware; typically for a microcontroller you will have an on-chip RTC clocked from an 32768Hz crystal.

In the [ARM implementation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlib/armlib_chr1359122861930.htm), the default stub uses semi-hosting to get time from the development host over JTAG/SWI, so will not work in a stand-alone system.  Either way you need to override the default implementation or stub with your own.

Your code should contain something like:

```
#if defined __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    time_t time( std::time_t *timeptr ) 
    {
        time_t epoch_time  = 0 ;
        struct tm time_struct = {0} ;

        // Your code to get RTC data in a tm struct here
        ...

        // Convert tm struct to UNIX epoch time     
        epoch_time = std::mktime( &time_struct ) ;

        if( tp != 0 )
        {
            *timeptr = epoch_time ; 
        }

        return epoch_time ; 
    }

#if defined __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Code using this function should include time.h/ctime to get the prototype.  The linker will resolve calls to `time()` to your implementation, overriding any existing default library implementation or stub.

If you have no RTC hardware, a hardware timer running at 1Hz manually initialised to the epoch time count or initialised from some external source (via networking for example) could be implemented.

When reading RTC hardware (or any other time source) you need to make sure the time is consistent; it is possible for example to read the 59 seconds, just as it rolls over to 00 seconds, and then read the minutes and so end up with say 20 minutes 59 seconds, when it should be 19 minutes 59 seconds, or 20 minutes 00 seconds.  The same applies to the roll-over of minute, hour, day, month and year.

Answer (score 0):

HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc,&sTime,RTC_FORMAT_BIN);

```
HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc,&sDate,RTC_FORMAT_BCD);
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n",sTime.Hours,sTime.Minutes,sTime.Seconds);
```

this command are based on HAL_drivers , by enable the RTC we can use this code